# Visual studio 2015 debugger datetime format

Tags: visual-studio-2015

How to change debugger datetime format for visual studio 2015

On the same computer

With visual studio 2013: DateTime.Now = Without AM/PM

With visual studio 2015: DateTime.Now = With AM/PM

[Visual studio 2013](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MsKD.png)

[Visual studio 2015](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdpQ7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Since VS2015, all values in debugger are formatted based upon current culture:
 `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`. This produces the same result as calling the `.ToString()` method.